# Select row data replication

Tags: r

I am looking to replicate specific rows in a column by 3.

My data frame, called IID, consists of only one column and around 700 variables, but a small snippet looks like this:

```
10341
10561
10641
10912
11011
11012
111
1131
1132
```

So, for every singleton (10341 10561 10641 10912 111) I need to replicate the rows by 3.
For every Twin (11011 11012 & 1131 1132) I need to only replicate the second twin (which ends in the letter 2) by 3, and leave the first twin untouched.

Ultimately I would want this data to look like so:

```
10341
10341
10341
10561
10561
10561
10641
10641
10641
10912
10912
10912
11011
11012
11012
11012
111
111
111
1131
1132
1132
1132
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `group` column which gives a unique number for every single and twin value. If a group is a single value repeat it 3 times and if it is a twin repeat the first value (smaller) 1 time and the second one 3 times.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

IID %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(Family_No) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(Family_No - lag(Family_No, default = first(Family_No)) != 1)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(n = if(n() == 1) 3 else c(1, 3)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  uncount(n) %>%
  arrange(row) %>%
  select(-group, -row)
```

This returns :

```
#   Family_No
#1      10341
#2      10341
#3      10341
#4      10561
#5      10561
#6      10561
#7      10641
#8      10641
#9      10641
#10     10912
#11     10912
#12     10912
#13     11011
#14     11012
#15     11012
#16     11012
#17       111
#18       111
#19       111
#20      1131
#21      1132
#22      1132
#23      1132
```

**data**

```
IID <- data.frame(Family_No = c(10341, 10561, 10641, 10912, 11011, 11012, 111, 1131, 1132))
```